# Set the center with autoLayout between 2 elements in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, trailing

How can I set the green button(right Button) center between the "Enter Button" and "panel image".

I want to set the green button center like below photo.

[image]

At the red button(left button), I can set the autolayout property in storyboard like below, it's correct show at left center part:

[image]

But in the right part, I set the

```
 First Item: Right Button.CenterX
 Relation: Equal
 Second Item: Enter Button.Trailing.
 Constant: 0
 Priority:1000
 Multiplier: 0.5
```

The right button will offset to the left part. Not in the right part center.

How can I set the right button center between  the enter button and panel right side in autoLayout at Storyboard?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a super view (View1) to contain the right button, make width of View1 be 1/3 of the view's width, and then set the center of right button in View1. This support different rotations.

Comment: This works for centering the right button between the middle trailing and the superview trailing. But what if I want the right button's center to be, say, 0.6 of the distance between middle trailing and superview trailing?